# Crawler says, page not found, but browser says otherwise

Tags: web-crawlers, 404

I'm stumped.

Google has been reporting increasing numbers of 404 errors for my website.  But my site is static.  Ok.  Maybe they just finding more as different chunks are scanned.

At the same time, I can put the errant URL in my address bar, and it shows up.

If you want to see the error in action,

My home page loads just fine, but produces errors when I use a link checker or when google comes calling.

Comment: We would need more information. Generally speaking, Google will not see a 404 so there is a disconnect somewhere. A 404 is your web server saying the page does not exist. It could be from a bad link somewhere on your site or on the net. These things happen of course. Can you give us an example URL that Google is trying to access? Change the domain name to example.com. Are you able to cut and paste the 404'ed URL directly into your browser? Is the domain name correct or using an IP address? Something is amiss.

Comment: Another thought, use the Google Search Console Fetch as Google to fetch a suspect page and then check both the access and error logs. Keep in mind, that log file caches may have to flush before you see an entry. This can be 5 minutes or longer depending upon web activity. Some installs will flush more often. So you may have to check again later. You should see the Google fetch and see what may be going on. It is possible that fetch will work okay. If so, you can also use the Submit to Index option and not worry about it. Cheers!!

Comment: It's Google acting up. I had a spike in error reports recently as well. The reports are bogus. They mostly consist of made-up URLs that are the product of Google's heuristic trying to find content accessed with JS where the URLs can't be found directly. If you want to be sure, use web-sniffer.net configured to use Googlebot UA. Look for the error code returned.

Answer (score 1):

First go to [Google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home).
If you haven't add your website, click Add a property button and verify your website ownership.
After you get into the Dashboard, click Crawl -> [Crawl Errors](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-errors) on the left panel.
Then scroll down..
You will see every crawl errors that was happen for your site on there.

 And make sure you click Mark As Fixed after you fix the errors.
But if you still receive error reports from google even you can open the URL, click Fetch as Google on the left panel and click Fetch and Render.